# How to create line chart in Excel with two series of ordinal/nominal data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have these two columns in Excel.

```
Result  Speed
------  ----
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
LOW LOW
LOW LOW
LOW LOW
LOW LOW
LOW LOW
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
HIGH    HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
MEDIUM  HIGH
LOW HIGH
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  LOW
LOW LOW
LOW LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
LOW LOW
LOW LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
LOW MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
LOW LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
LOW MEDIUM
LOW MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
MEDIUM  MEDIUM
LOW MEDIUM
MEDIUM  LOW
LOW LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
LOW LOW
LOW LOW
MEDIUM  LOW
```

How do I create a line chart with two lines to represent this data?
When I select the data and try to add the line chart, nothing gets presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you don't have anything to chart. "High", "Medium", and "Low" are not values so Excel can't make any sense out of them. You may as well try charting a list of car models on a line. You can convert "High", "medium", and "Low" to numbers so that Excel can chart it with a formula like: `=IF(A1="High", 3, IF(A1="Medium", 2, IF(A1="Low", 1, "")))` Assuming your data for row 1 starts in cell A1. Then highlight your two columns of numbers and insert a new line chart.